# Use jq to unify unknown JSON to known schema

Tags: json, jq

I'm not really sure on how to phrase this question so lemme give an example: I have two types of JSON document formats for a large amount of files. Most of the contents apart from one object is irrelevant to me. I want to create a normalised version of each file. These are the two objects I care about (in each of the formats):

```
{
    "title": "Some data",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "123",
            ...
        },
        {
            "id": "abc",
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

and

```
{
  "title": "Some more data",
  "data": [
    {
      "ids": [
        {
          "id": "123",
          ...
        },
        {
          "id": "abc",
          ...
        }
      ],
      "names": [
        {
          "name": "A",
          ...
        },
        {
          "name": "B",
          ...
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Each of those "object formats" is an object inside a JSON array in a file. I want to convert each of the files I have into a list of objects that captures the `title`, list of `id` and list of `name` in a single object:

```
{
  "title": "Some more data",
  "ids": [
      "123",
      "abc"
  ],
  "names": [
      "A",
      "B"
  ]
}
```

I use the following `jq`, but it doesn't work (it creates multiple objects with the same title per `name` or `id`:

```
for f in $(find * -wholename "*.json" | sort); do
cat $f | jq '..
| if type == "object" then
    if has("data") then {
        "name": .title,
        "ids": (.data[] | [
            if has("id") then {
                "id": .id
            } else if has("ids") then {
                "ids": .ids[],
                "names": .names?
            } else null end
        end
    ])} else null end
else null end
| select(type != "null")' > "$f" ; done
```

EDIT: https://jqplay.org/s/uWC80Qoixxd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate over the outer array using `.[]`, then construct the objects using `? //` to provide alternatives if one evaluates to `null`.

If you are okay with `null`s in the comlpete absence of a key (as with `.name` in your first format), try this:

```bash
.[] | {title} + (.data | {
  ids: map(.ids[]? // . | .id),
  names: map(.names[]? // . | .name)
})
```

```json
{
  "title": "Some data",
  "ids": [
    "123",
    "abc"
  ],
  "names": [
    null,
    null
  ]
}
{
  "title": "Some more data",
  "ids": [
    "123",
    "abc"
  ],
  "names": [
    "A",
    "B"
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/AE9Agq7T9I_s)

But you could also filter out `null`s using `values`:

```bash
.[] | {title} + (.data | {
  ids: map(.ids[]? // . | .id | values),
  names: map(.names[]? // . | .name | values)
})
```

```json
{
  "title": "Some data",
  "ids": [
    "123",
    "abc"
  ],
  "names": []
}
{
  "title": "Some more data",
  "ids": [
    "123",
    "abc"
  ],
  "names": [
    "A",
    "B"
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/KnG5gUSEGAw)

If you want to get rid of keys with empty arrays altogether, filter them out using `map_values` on a comparison using `select`:

```bash
.[] | {title} + (.data | {
  ids: map(.ids[]? // . | .id | values),
  names: map(.names[]? // . | .name | values)
} | map_values(select(. != [])))
```

```json
{
  "title": "Some data",
  "ids": [
    "123",
    "abc"
  ]
}
{
  "title": "Some more data",
  "ids": [
    "123",
    "abc"
  ],
  "names": [
    "A",
    "B"
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/tMgti7417fz)

---

Edit using the modified input files: As the deeper levels use the same (relative) path (here `.specs[].spec`), we need some other distinction criteria to rule out the level with "Some title you don't care about". Checking for the presence of a `.data` key seems to fit with the new sample data.

```bash
.specs[].spec | select(has("data")), .specs[]?.spec
| {title} + (.data | {
  ids: map(.ids[]?.id // .i | values),
  names: map(.names[]? // . | .name | values)
} | map_values(select(. != [])))
```

```json
{
  "title": "Some data",
  "ids": [
    "123",
    "abc"
  ]
}
{
  "title": "Some more data",
  "ids": [
    "123",
    "abc"
  ],
  "names": [
    "A",
    "B"
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/et8BDz8LaXc)

Comment: Thank you! This brought me a lot closer to my goal! And looks way simpler! I just noticed I just missed two very important pieces of information and will edit my post accordingly:

1. The objects I talked about are not in an array at the root level. The array can be nested on a different level, depending on the format: For the first format, it is a root level field, e.g. `{ "specs": [ "spec": { // format one obj... } ] }`, for the second, it is nested two levels deeper (but using same keys), e.g. `{ "specs": [ "spec": { "specs": [ "spec": { // format two obj... } ] } ] }`.

Comment: And 2. The `id` key is actually different for format one and two: `i` and `id` (my bad).

Comment: https://jqplay.org/s/uWC80Qoixxd

Comment: (For the sake of simplicity, I could put both in an array for jqplay).

Comment: @LuMa I have added another version using your modified input data. But I only added the "last" variant, i.e. strip out `values` and `map_values` as you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

If you are okay with having `names: null` or `names: []` in the final document for your first example, the following looks like a simple solution:

```
{ title }
+ (.data | {
    ids: map(.ids[].id),
    names: (map(.names[].name)? // []) # or // null
})
```

or equivalent:

```
{
    title,
    ids: (.data | map(.ids[].id)),
    names: (.data | map(.names[].name)? // [])
}
```

Output 1:

```json
{
  "title": "Some more data",
  "ids": [
    "123",
    "abc"
  ],
  "names": []
}
```

Output 2:

```json
{
  "title": "Some more data",
  "ids": [
    "123",
    "abc"
  ],
  "names": [
    "A",
    "B"
  ]
}
```